# Draw particles trajectories of undefined length with opengl

Tags: opengl

I have to draw a physical simulation that displays trajectories of moving around particles. 3D position data are read from a database in realtime while drawing. Once set up a VBO for each object, the drawing call will be the standard `glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, size)`. The problem is that VBOs storing trail points are updated every frame since new points are added. This seems to me extremely inefficient! Furthermore what if I want to draw the trajectories with a gradient color from the particle's actual position to the older points? I have to update the color of all vertices in the VBO at every draw call! What is the standard way through this kind of stuff?

To summarize:

- I want draw lines of undefined - potentially infinite - length (the length increase with time).
- I want the color of points in the trajectories to shade based on the actual relative position on the trajectories (for example white in the beginning (actual particle position), black in the end (first particle position), grey in middle).

I read many tutorials but I haven't found nothing about drawing ever-updating and indefinitely-growing lines... I will appreciate any suggestion! Thanks!

Comment: Fixed-function or programmable pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use multiple VBOs so that you have a fixed number of vertices per.  That way you only have to modify the last VBO in the sequence when you add new points instead of completely updating one giant VBO.
2. Add a sequence number vertex attribute or use `gl_VertexID` and pass in the total point count as a uniform.  Then you can divide a given vertex's sequence number by the total count and use that fraction to mix between your gradient colors.

Comment: Ok, thanks! One more question: to update vertices I call glBufferData() that take the array of vertices... There is a way to buffer only last position without remember all vertices in the VBO?

Comment: @bluePhlavio: [`glBufferSubData()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) will let you do in-place updates, though you can't grow a buffer that way.

Comment: Why I cannot grow a buffer that way?

Comment: @bluePhlavio: From the doc: "`offset` and `size` must define a range lying entirely within the buffer object's data store."